# Selenium Driver Proxy wont connect to page Not Secure Error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy

Using Selenium to try and connect to this page comes up with Internal Server Error. Next to the link on the address bar it says "Not Secure" and it has **https** Crossed out.

```
from zyte_smartproxy_selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Edge(spm_options={'spm_apikey': '<MY API KEY HERE>'})
browser.get('https://www.somedomain.com/accounts/login')
```

This is the result I get on the page

```
Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS secure handshake works fine when I connect to the URL you cited:

```
$ curl -i https://www.somedomain.com/accounts/login
HTTP/1.1 410 Gone
Date: Sat, 17 Feb 2024 01:23:33 GMT
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

410 - gone
```

If you want us to examine the cert chain for a **different** URL
of interest, then you'll have to correctly spell it in your Question.
When debugging https problems, the details matter.

Comment: Correct link would be curl -i https: //www.instagram.com/accounts/login. it seems to return more data but looks like it establishes a connection just fine. Could it be that its getting rejected because of the proxy